# Error sending email using nodemailer via Office365 smtp (MEANjs scaffold)

Tags: node.js, email, office365, meanjs, nodemailer

I'm trying to use Office365 SMTP to send email using Nodemailer (in a MEANjs scaffold), but I get the following error:

```
[Error: 140735277183760:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:795:]
```

I'm using the following Nodemailer options:

```
{ 
    host: 'smtp.office365.com',
    port: '587',
    auth: { user: 'xxxx', pass: 'xxxx' },
    secure: 'false',
    tls: { ciphers: 'SSLv3' }
}
```

Removing the *tls* field doesn't make a difference. What am I missing?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The solution was simple. The 'secure' field should be 'secureConnection'. The MEANjs scaffold that generated the configs created mailer options with the 'secure' field. The rest of the options are fine. For anyone that needs a working Office365 SMTP nodemailer options block, the following should work:

```
{ 
    host: 'smtp.office365.com',
    port: '587',
    auth: { user: 'xxxx', pass: 'xxxx' },
    secureConnection: false,
    tls: { ciphers: 'SSLv3' }
}
```

Comment: When I tried using the opts you supplied it didn't worked and gave a timeout error. I had to remove the `secureConnection` opt for it to work. Thank you!

Comment: thank you very much! in my case it worked with this setting: `"secure": false,
      "tls": { "ciphers": "SSLv3" }`

Answer (score 18):

I know this is old but if anyone looks this up in 2019, you can just add 
`service: "Outlook365"`

and you won't have to specify connection options.

[Node Mailer Docs](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/well-known/)

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "Outlook365",
    auth: {
      user: 'FROMUSER@office365.com',
      pass: 'FROMUSERPASS'
    },    
  })

  let info = transporter.sendMail({
    from: 'FROMUSER@office365.com',
    to: 'TOUSER@office365.com',
    subject: 'Test',
    text: 'hello world',
    html: '<h1>TEST</h1>'
  })
```

Answer (score 7):

This nodemailer documentation https://nodemailer.com/2-0-0-beta/setup-smtp/ indeed states options.secure and not options.secureConnection. It also suggests, in an example, that options.secure is expecting a boolean value true or false and not a string value `'true'` or `'false'`. Removing the `''` from around `'false'` works for me.

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow. I'm wondering why the down-vote for a valid answer. All Simon H did was put grey boxes around some of the text. Harsh when my intension is to help people.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the username and password were spelled correctly but I did not login in the Account after creation. So I used a mail program (Thunderbird) to login once and had to change my password and then I had access over Nodemailer.