# nodemailer send mail not working

Tags: node.js, email, smtp, nodemailer

I'm currently trying to send a mail out of nodemailer.

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp1.mailserver.com',
    port: 25,
    secure: false
});

app.post('/email', function (req, res) {
    var body = req.body;
    var mailAdresses = body.email;
    var image = body.image;
    var text = body.emailText;

    // setup email data with unicode symbols
    let mailOptions = {
        from: 'myadress@mailserver.com', // sender address
        to: mailAdresses, // list of receivers
        subject: 'Image', // Subject line
        html: text, // html body,
        attachments: [
            {
                filename: "whiteboard.png",
                content: image.split("base64,")[1],
                encoding: 'base64'
            }
        ]
    };

    //send mail with defined transport object
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);
    });
```

That is the code I'm using. I first tried port 587, then I got an error saying

```
{ Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 15.241.140.74:587
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1050:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1073:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1093:14)
  code: 'ECONNECTION',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '15.241.140.74',
  port: 587,
  command: 'CONN' }
```

Then I tried with port 25 and with auth, then I get

```
 code: 'EAUTH',
  response: '503 5.5.1 Error: authentication not enabled',
  responseCode: 503,
  command: 'AUTH PLAIN' }
```

And now I tried it without AUTH and I get:

```
 code: 'EENVELOPE',
       response: '450 4.7.1 <[127.0.0.1]>: Helo command rejected: Service temporarily unavailable',
       responseCode: 450,
       command: 'RCPT TO',
       recipient: 'anotheraddress@address.com' } ] }
```

And I don't get the problem.

The mail server is a corporate mail server that uses outlook365, I can use the mailbox through outlook and its working fine, and I don't find the problem.

Does anybody know the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29812132/ddg#29812364

Comment: @MySidesTheyAreGone you mean I should use `secureConnection` field?

Comment: @MySidesTheyAreGone same result with that. also, I just added a `transporter.verify` and it doesn't throw an error, so the SMTP connection somehow seems to be working

Comment: Worth a try :) Sorry I didn't clarify immediately.

Comment: @MySidesTheyAreGone yes I tried so many things to I have no problem with trying more things, but yeah, same result.. and the question is why. I also tried another `to` mail address, but same...

Answer (score 0):

**For authentication not enabled error**

**you have to add

tls: {rejectUnauthorized: false } property.**

```
nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp1.mailserver.com',

    port: 25,

    tls:{
         rejectUnauthorized: false          
        } 
   });
```